# How many visits did the Mitford sisters or Oswald Mosley make to Nazi Germany?

Tags: 20th-century, nazi-germany, england, nazism, fascism

The youngest [Mitford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitford_family) sister, [Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_Mitford), first met [Hitler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Hitler) in Munich 1934, who invites her older sister [Diana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diana_Mitford) over to meet him in April 1935. Sometime in 1935 Unity delivers the televised speech at Hesselberg Festival with [Julius Streicher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julius_Streicher). October 1936 Diana and [Oswald Mosley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oswald_Mosley) get married at [Goebbels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Goebbels)' home. Unity was again in Munich in 1939 when she attempted suicide, but would like to know which number of her overall trips was this, i.e. duration of each of her stays.

The above total to 5 visits by the Mitford sisters to Nazi Germany, but unconfirmed if any were part of the same visit. Were there any other widely publicized trips they made to the country? Especially interested in their goings and returns to London, i.e. detailed itinerary and duration of how long each of their stays lasted for.

Bonus for tracking Oswald Mosley's movements during this time period too, accompanied with his wife Diana or not.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Laura Thompson's "The Six?" (St Martin's Press, New York, 2015). I read it some years ago but don't recall the details re: specifically who visited when & how often. I was impressed by the detailed research.

Comment: This would be much improved as an answer if you could find and cite the details.

Comment: Planned to, could you outline some of their major visits from memory?